# Revolution slider not appearing (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm new to using Wordpress and Revolution slider.

I've got one of the included 'themes' set-up and embedded on the homepage of [my website](http://www.kentcinema.co.uk/) but it doesn't appear (Appears in the source code).

When I do the same but for the side bar menu widget it appears!

Any ideas all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the relevant code, bro.

Comment: it sounds like the height isn't set properly.  if the slider is in the source code but you can't see it thats probably why!